# Displaying the FPS of webcam with OpenCV using time_t start, end

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam, frame-rate

Before I begin I've tried using:

```
int cvGetCaptureProperty( CvCapture* capture, int property_id);
```

with `property_id = CV_CAP_PROP_FPS`

That just outputs 0, doesn't work for a webcam.

This is my code, Im converting from RGB to HSV to track objects, and I would like to know what the webcam is running at.

The following code outputs a FPS of 1.2-3.5, which makes sense if opencv is capturing raw video and sending it down the USB of the webcam. However it is obviously running higher as the output video is rather smooth, am I being stupid here and do I need to measure the system FPS?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

const int FRAME_WIDTH = 640;
const int FRAME_HEIGHT = 480;
//max number of objects to be detected in frame
const int MAX_NUM_OBJECTS=50;
const string windowName = "Original Image";
const string windowName1 = "HSV Image";
const string windowName2 = "Thresholded Image";
const string windowName3 = "After Morphological Operations";
const string trackbarWindowName = "Trackbars";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    time_t start, end;
    double fps;
    int counter = 0;
    double sec;
    time(&start);

    Mat cameraFeed;
    Mat threshold;
    Mat HSV;

    VideoCapture capture(1);  // 0,1,2, your cam id there

    capture.open(1);

    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_WIDTH);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,FRAME_HEIGHT);
    while(1)
    {
        capture.read(cameraFeed);
        cvtColor(cameraFeed,HSV,COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    }

    imshow(windowName,cameraFeed);

    while(2)
    {
    capture >> cameraFeed;
    time(&end);
    ++counter;        
    sec = difftime (end, start);      
    fps = counter / sec;
    printf("FPS = %.2f\n", fps);
    }

    waitKey(30);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried putting the:

```
    while(2)
    {
    capture >> cameraFeed;
    time(&end);
    ++counter;        
    sec = difftime (end, start);      
    fps = counter / sec;
    printf("FPS = %.2f\n", fps);
    }
```

within its own `while(2)` in the main function, this measures the FPS between 23 and 28, which is what I would assume the camera is running at, however the output on the screen is just a blank grey box, it doesn't display what the camera is capturing.

I'm at a loss here, calculating the FPS with either method gives me something I need but not both!

By the way, I'm using OpenCV 248, Logitech HD 720p Webcam, Windows 7, VS 2010 x86.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measure OpenCV FPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148826/measure-opencv-fps)

Comment: The FPS retrived via OpenCV's API only works for video files, not live streams.

Comment: You code doesn't compile. MAke sure you share a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: This should be self contained http://pastebin.com/AXZ2FMDa apologies

Comment: Ok, I edited the question to share that code. Hopefully someone has time to help you out. Good luck!

Comment: Yea I did the same, thanks anyway! And unfortunately I worked out that the API only works for videos files after a lengthy few hours a few days ago.